# Adding Server Client Event on my <input> tag ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, event-handling, server-side

I need to trigger an event handler on my server side through this input tag

```
<div id="ck-button">
       <label>
          <input type="checkbox" runat="server" value="1" onserverchange="input_click" /><span>red</span>
       </label>
    </div>
```

and i tried following code to capture event, but it is not firing `input_click`.

```
 protected void input_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "alert", "alert('You have clicked the button!');", true);
}
```

Thanks i really need help in this one.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set AutoPostBack=true to fire that event. But it is a HTML control not an ASP.Net control, you can achieve as follows.

`<input type="checkbox" runat="server" value="1" onserverchange="input_click" id="chk" onchange="javascript: form1.submit();" /><span>red</span>`

I assume you have `<form id="form1" ...` , if `form` has different id, then use that in place of `form1`.